# how to run .bat file with pass some parameter in powershell script?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

In my machine , this location content , windows bat file. "`D/too/w.bat`". This bat file can run in cmd , like this `w.bat I :/ o:/` In Powershell , can run like this "`./w.bat i: o:/`" . now I , need to run it using some automated .ps script. I try like bellow ,

```
    #
    function run--bat {
     Write-host "run bat";
     Start-Process -File "C:/t/w.bat" "i:/ o:/"
    }
```

but i it not succes. need some expert help to resolve this .

Comment: Why are you using powershell to run a batch file? It would probably be better if you just take whatever is in that batch file and add it as commands directly in powershell too. Also As this is obviously for Windows, those forward slashes should be backward slashes, because that is what Windows uses for root directories and path separators. Also as your question is simply due to your failure to read the help information for the `start-process` command, it is off topic, because you would have clearly noticed the `-ArgumentList` & `-FilePath` parameters output: `get-help start-process -detailed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an argument list:

```
Start-Process C:\t\w.bat -ArgumentList 'i:\','o:\'
```

The comma operator builds arrays in PowerShell, so `'i:\','o:\'` is a two-element array.

`Start-Process` will join the arguments with spaces in order to create the finalized command line. This means you could also pass both arguments as one string:

```
Start-Process C:\t\w.bat -ArgumentList 'i:\ o:\'
```

From `w.bat`'s point of view there will be no difference.

To pass a value that contains spaces - such as a path - as a single argument, you need to wrap it in double quotes:

```
Start-Process C:\t\w.bat -ArgumentList '"i:\something\with spaces"','o:\'
```

Then `w.bat` will see two arguments:

- `%1` = `"i:\something\with spaces"` (and `%~1` = `i:\something\with spaces`)
- `%2` = `o:\`